# unable to remove a dynamically created Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am dynamically creating a div using jquery named "sampageswrapper", the thing is that I want to check if the div name `sampageswrapper` is already created then delete it.

```
<div id="container2" class="container" style="width:600px; height: 700px" name="container2">
Enter Color Name and use + to add more colors:
<input id="byname" type="text" name="byname">
<br>
<br>
<div class="sampageswrapper">
<div class="pagenumbering" align="center" style="clear: both; margin-top:12px; color:#FFF">
<div class="buttons">
</div>
<div class="pagecount" align="center">
</div>
<div class="sampageswrapper">
</div>
```

And following is my JS/Jquery Code

```
    if ($("#sampageswrapper").length > 0) {
                jQuery('#container2').find('#sampageswrapper').remove();
//i also tried jQuery('#sampageswrapper').remove();
            }
```

But I am unable to remove the div please guide me.

Comment: You're using an id selector, but you seem to be creating the divs with  that as the class?

Comment: Also make sure that your HTML markup is correct, before starting doing something with Javascript.

Comment: sorry but i am still learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem like you have duplicated `id`, since `id` must be unique you can use class instead for your dynamically added elements, then you can do:

```
if ($("#container2 .sampageswrapper").length > 0) {
    jQuery('#container2').find('.sampageswrapper').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are selecting `sampageswrapper` based on ID, but you should test on the class.

```
jQuery('#container2').find('.sampageswrapper').remove(); 
jQuery('#container2 .sampageswrapper').remove(); // works too
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to remove an object with `id` sampageswrapper, but in the html that is the class names. Use `.sampageswrapper` instead in your remove statement!

Answer (score 1):

Add a breakpoint:

```
if ($("#sampageswrapper").length > 0) {
   debugger;
   jQuery('#container2').find('#sampageswrapper').remove();
}
```

Open console and refresh page, once it stops on the breakpoint, in console run this:

```
jQuery('#container2')
```

Make sure it returns the object you expect.  Then run this in console:

```
jQuery('#container2').find('#sampageswrapper')
```

Here you'll see it returns nothing.  This is because the `'#sampageswrapper'` selector is wrong and should be a class selector instead:

```
jQuery('#container2').find('.sampageswrapper')
```

**You should be going through this process whenever you have a problem with code that involves jquery selectors, so that you can focus in on the specific selector that is causing the problem.**

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($(".sampageswrapper").length > 0) {
   jQuery('#container2').find('.sampageswrapper').remove();
}
```

use class selector instead of id selector